# Publishing to kafka successful and database update fails , how to maintain consistency in distributed system

Tags: database, apache-kafka, transactions

I am working on a distributed system (eCommerce) and using Kafka events for communication between systems. So according to our business logic, we are first publishing to Kafka topic (which is successful) and after that, we are updating the oracle database. Sometimes this update in database fails , how to maintain state consistency in between systems ? As the other system will update its database with new status of order but the producer will have the old status only, so how to reduce this inconsistency ?

Answer (score 0):

What you are using actually calling dual writing which can cause perpetual inconsistency due to many ugly problems like partial failures like your case, race condition...

An approach I find quite interesting is using `change data capture` to keep different data system in sync which each other.

Highly recommend this talk, blog of Martin Kleppmann about how to use this kind of architecture:

1. [Using logs to build a solid data infrastructure](https://www.confluent.io/blog/using-logs-to-build-a-solid-data-infrastructure-or-why-dual-writes-are-a-bad-idea/)
2. [Staying in Sync: from Transactions to Streams](https://www.infoq.com/presentations/event-streams-kafka/)